# Why does href="example.com" not open example.com in new tab? Instead it opens a new tab but appends example.com to the end of the current URL

Tags: html

I have these 3 following `<a>` tags that point to different hrefs. 1 and 2 work fine and open `https://example.com` and `http://example.com` in a new tab, but the 3rd one open the same URL as the one I'm currently on and just appends `example.com` to the end

Why is this happening?

```html
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Open</a>
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Open</a>
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">Open</a>
```

Comment: That's called a relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third one is a link to the **page** named `example.com` *on the current server*.

Just because it has a `.com` extension does not mean it is magically a domain name. It's like that by design and by definition.

The first piece of text (until the first `/` after it, if any) is treated as a domain name if and only if there is `//` or `protocol://` at the beginning. And the text is treated as a (sub)page if there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp it seems that you are using a `relative` URL which assumes that you are navigating to a page that exists in the same website. This is why it tacks on the `href` attribute to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

It's because without the protocol (`http://` `https://` `ftp://` etc) the path is treated as relative to current domain.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score -1):

This is called relative path.

Try this out instead
Open